# MaiKit authentication failed when send email

Tags: c#

MailKit library for send email worked ok for company smtp server, but for some reason it start failing during Authentication.

Error is: **535: Authentication failed. Restarting authentication process.**

Standard System.Net.Mail works for this mail server, but not MailKit;

we tried several configuration of security mode.

Log is following:

Connected to smtp://smtp.mycompn.de:25/?starttls=when-available
S: 220 smtp.mycompn.de ESMTP
C: EHLO DE-IN193
S: 250-smtp.mycompn.de
S: 250-SIZE 20480000
S: 250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN
S: 250 HELP
C: AUTH PLAIN ********
S: 535 Authentication failed. Restarting authentication process.
C: AUTH LOGIN
S: 334 VXN...
C: ********
S: 334 UGF...
C: ********
S: 535 Authentication failed. Restarting authentication process.
C: QUIT
S: 221 goodbye

What could be cause ?

Thank you in advanced.